# How do I keep files that have already been copied over from being copied?

Tags: python, operating-system, shutil

I'm using the following code and it just starts over and will run forever if I let it.  I'm trying to let it skip files already in there and stop when all the files have been copied.

```
import os
import shutil

source_dir = r"D:\\Tibi"
target_dir = r"D:\\fileSave/"
extensions = (".mp4", ".CR2")

while True:
    try:
        for directory, _, file_names in os.walk(source_dir):
            for file_name in file_names:
                if file_name.endswith(extensions):
                    source_path = os.path.join(directory, file_name)
                    target_path = os.path.join(target_dir, file_name)
                    print("Moving {} to {} from {}".format(file_name, target_dir, directory))
                    shutil.copy(source_path, target_dir)


except shutil.SameFileError:
    print("{} is already in the folder".format(file_name))
```

Note that I put the exception in there because it would hardstop when it found a file in the folder that was already in there.

Comment: Of course it runs forever. You have it in a `while True` loop that never breaks...

Comment: So if I take out the while True statement. it will break the loop when it's done?  But then how do I keep it  from copying files that are already in there?

Comment: It will stop when your `os.walk` iterator is exhausted.

Comment: Before you copy a file, check to see if it has already been copied...

Comment: I tried adding `if file_name in directory == file_name in target_dir: break else: 'continue'`  I'm pretty sure that the file_name is different in each target due to the os.path.join command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.listdir()` to create a list of all the files and folders in the directory and then use a for iterate through the list of files

Something like this should suffice

```
import os

files = os.listdir("D:\\Tibi")

for file in files:
    "copy files..."
```